# Write down in roster notation all the elements of 2 ∖ 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Work over the universal set  = {1,2,3,4,5}. Let 0 = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5}}. For each  ∈ ℤ⩾0, define +1 = { ∩  ∶ ,  ∈ } ∪ { ∪  ∶ ,  ∈ } ∪ { ∶  ∈ }. (a) Write down in roster notation all the elements of 2 ∖ 1. (b) What is the smallest  ∈ ℤ⩾0 satisfying +1 = ? (c) What is the cardinality of U∈ℤ⩾0?

Hi, this is the answers which I got which i suspect to be wrong. Kindly let me know if they are. Thanks! a) { {{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,3}}, {{1,2,3,4,5}, {3}, {1,2,3}}, {{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {3}}, {{3}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,3}} } Or {} b) n = 1 c) U = 4

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a "do it for me" site, but we'd be happy to help if you can explain your progress so far and where you're stuck :) It would also help to [format your post with MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi, this is the answers which I got which i suspect to be wrong. Kindly let me know if they are. Thanks!
a)
{ 
{{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,3}}, 
{{1,2,3,4,5}, {3}, {1,2,3}}, 
{{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {3}},
{{3}, {3,4,5}, {1,2,3}}
}
Or {}
b) n = 1
c) U = 4

Comment: This is unreadable.